# How to detect user started or ended any activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app that gets the user location, and I want to notify the client if he starts an activity like running or driving, I followed this guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions

I look for another guide that I found 
https://androidkt.com/transition-api/
but still it didn't work out
but it wont work for me, this is my relevant code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetecdActivity.class);
    transitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    List<ActivityTransition> transitions = new ArrayList<>();

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.STILL)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    ActivityTransitionRequest request = new ActivityTransitionRequest(transitions);
    Task<Void> task = ActivityRecognition.getClient(this)
            .requestActivityTransitionUpdates(request, transitionPendingIntent);

    task.addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    // Handle success
                }
            }
    );

    task.addOnFailureListener(
            new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
    );

//subclass
 public class DetecdActivity extends IntentService {

    public DetecdActivity(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (ActivityTransitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            ActivityTransitionResult result = ActivityTransitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            for (ActivityTransitionEvent event : result.getTransitionEvents()) {
                // chronological sequence of events....
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), event.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


//in the manifest

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

<service
        android:name=".MapsActivity$DetecdActivity"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly? Have you setup google play services properly?

Comment: the issue that its not working at all, what do you mean setup google play serviece ?if i had the depenecie ,yes i had